# I added a checkbox in my XML code and got a very weird output

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

I added this check box in my XML file. I didn't get a checkbox in my output. I got something weird. I'm a beginner here. I have put my XML code below and the image of how the checkbox looks like in the attachments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout         
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you like Tutorials Point"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have attached a photo of the output I am getting.

[image]

Comment: guys click the "enter image description" to look at the output of the code im getting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue of Android API 24. Selecting API 23 will solve the problem. 
[How to select API 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci9I6.png)